# Kotlin: Remove list in Recycerview using AlertDialog button

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I hope to remove items in Recyclerview by AlertDialog button.
Do you have idea?

Adapter & Viewholer

```
class ProjectsRecyclerAdapter(val list:List<ProjectListDataModel>, var clickListner: OnProjectListClickListner) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectRecyclerViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProjectRecyclerViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_cardview, parent, false)
        return ProjectRecyclerViewHolder(
            view
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectRecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.initialize(list[position], clickListner)

    }
}

class ProjectRecyclerViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    fun initialize(item: ProjectListDataModel, action: OnProjectListClickListner) {
        itemView.projectNameText.text = item.name
        itemView.modifiedTimeText.text = item.modTime
        itemView.descriptionText.text = item.description

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            action.onItemClick(item, adapterPosition)
        }

    }
}

interface  OnProjectListClickListner {
    fun onItemClick(item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int)
}
```

And here is Main Activity

```
class LocalProjectListActivity :
    AppCompatActivity(),
    OnProjectListClickListner,
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main)

        val localProjectList = listOf(
            ProjectListDataModel(
                "Project A",
                "Sun, 01/DEC/2020, 22:23GMT",
                "Testing 1",
                "AAAA",
                "A, A",
                8,
                232
            ),
            ProjectListDataModel(
                "Project B",
                "Sun, 01/JUL/2020, 10:23GMT",
                "Testing 2",
                "BBBB",
                "B, B",
                6,
                354
            ),
            ProjectListDataModel(
                "Project C",
                "Sun, 11/MAR/2020, 08:31GMT",
                "Testing 3",
                "CCCC",
                "C,C",
                15,
                632
            )
        )

        val adapter = ProjectsRecyclerAdapter(localProjectList, this)
        projectNameText.adapter = adapter
        projectNameText.setHasFixedSize(true)
        projectNameText.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    override fun onItemClick(item: ProjectListDataModel, position: Int) {

        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val ad = builder.create()
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.project_onclick, null)
        dialogView.projectNameText.text = item.name
        dialogView.modifiedTimeText.text = item.modTime
        dialogView.descriptionText.text = item.description
        dialogView.fileNumberText.text = item.fileNumber.toString() + "EA"
        dialogView.fileSizeText.text = item.fileSize.toString() + "MB"
        dialogView.scopeText.text = item.scope
        dialogView.userIdText.text = item.resposible
        ad.setView(dialogView)
        ad.show()


        //when click Load button
            dialogView.loadButton.setOnClickListener {
            ad.dismiss()

            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            dialog.setTitle("Question1")
            dialog.setMessage("You want to go to the project?")
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
            })
            dialog.setNegativeButton("No", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
                val fileFilterIntent = Intent(this, ProjectFileActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(fileFilterIntent)
            })
            dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", DialogInterface.OnClickListener {dialog, _ ->
                dialog.dismiss()
            })
            //if(isMarker == true) {
            dialog.show()
            //} else {}
        }

        dialogView.deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
            ad.dismiss()

            val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

            dialog.setTitle("Delet project list")
            dialog.setMessage("You want to delete project?")
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", DialogInterface.OnClickListener { _, _ ->
                **//Delete items in RecyclerView**
            })
            dialog.setNeutralButton("Cancel", null)
            dialog.show()
        }
        dialogView.cancleButton.setOnClickListener { ad.dismiss() }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.remoteProjects -> {
                val serverProjIntent = Intent(this, ServerProjectListActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(serverProjIntent)
            }
            R.id.settings -> {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Go to Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        mainLocal.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }

}
```

I posted all the code like that.
I can get the lists using Recyclerview, and made the AlertDialog But I don't know how to delete the items using the "Yes" button in AlertDialog.

Please give me some advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have a reference to the list and the adapter outside of onCreate

```
private val localProjectList = mutableListOf(
    ProjectListDataModel(
        "Project A",
        "Sun, 01/DEC/2020, 22:23GMT",
        "Testing 1",
        "AAAA",
        "A, A",
        8,
        232
    ),
    ProjectListDataModel(
        "Project B",
        "Sun, 01/JUL/2020, 10:23GMT",
        "Testing 2",
        "BBBB",
        "B, B",
        6,
        354
    ),
    ProjectListDataModel(
        "Project C",
        "Sun, 11/MAR/2020, 08:31GMT",
        "Testing 3",
        "CCCC",
        "C,C",
        15,
        632
    )
)

private lateinit var adapter: ProjectsRecyclerAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)

    adapter = ProjectsRecyclerAdapter(localProjectList, this)
    projectNameText.adapter = adapter
    projectNameText.setHasFixedSize(true)
    projectNameText.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
}
```

And then delete the list and notify the adapter

```
private fun deleteItemsAndNotifyAdapter() {
    localProjectList.clear()
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

You can delete and notify adapter in you dialog:

```
private var alertDialog: AlertDialog? = null
private fun showDeleteDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.run {
        setTitle("Delete project list")
        setMessage("You want to delete project?")
        setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
            deleteItemsAndNotifyAdapter()
        }
        setNegativeButton("Cancel") { _, _ ->
        }
    }

    alertDialog = builder.create()
    alertDialog?.show
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, however, could you let me know where I can put the delete list and notify adapter code detailly?

Comment: I added code for creating an alert dialog that does this. @SeanKim

Comment: hmm.. when I run whole app was turned off..T.T

Comment: Did it crash? Can you add the stack trace from your log?

Comment: I got an error message, 'Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch', on `private fun deleteItemsAndNotifyAdapter(){
        localProjectList.clear()
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }` the `clear` seems to be declared..

Comment: And, can you explain where do I put the `private fun deleteItemsAndNotifyAdapter() {
    localProjectList.clear()
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}` code? I just put after the onCreate, not inside, in the Main Activity. Dose it right?

Comment: Yes the function should be outside of onCreate. And you need to change your localProjectList from listOf to mutableListOf. Have edited my example. The difference between List and MutableList is that List is read-only, you can't change it. With MutableList you can read and Write, so you can delete or add items if you want.

Comment: Wow! perfect! but one error on `adapter = ProjectsRecyclerAdapter(localProjectList, this)` . So, I changed like this,  `adapter = ProjectsRecyclerAdapter(localProjectList as ArrayList<ProjectListDataModel>, this)`, then it's working perfectly!

Comment: that's great Sean :)